# How to rank by top 100 item sales, by week?

Tags: sas

We have a SAS pull with a huge amount of items and their sales by week. We need the data to be top 100 items by week. 52 weeks would give us 5,200 total rows vs. the mass data we have now. How do you modify the code to perform such a task?
I'm quite new to SAS and understand how to pull and create basic filters but something this in-depth is over my head.

Comment: Could you show what code you are running?  This site is for fixing code, not writing code.  You'll want to use a sort or proc rank.

Comment: Are you using SAS EG, DI or Base? Can you include anything you've tried so far?  Is your data on a RDMS? If so, do you have pass through access?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to sort by week and week_sales and select only first 100 in each week group.

```
* one sales amount row per item/week;
proc sort data=weekly_sales;
  by week descending sales;

data top100s; 
  set weekly_sales;
  by week;

  if first.week 
    then within_group_counter = 1;
    else within_group_counter + 1;

  if within_group_counter <= 100;
run;
```

There are probably at least six other ways, maybe even half a dozen, to get the same result.